# Layout does not applied in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I tried a template where I put the layout in a folder (/views/layout) and named it mainlayout.blade.php.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Ogani Template">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Ogani, unica, creative, html">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>My Web | {{ $title }}</title>

    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cairo:wght@200;300;400;600;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Css Styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/elegant-icons.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/nice-select.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slicknav.min.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"> 
</head>

<body>
    <!-- Js Plugins -->
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nice-select.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mixitup.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I create the first page to simulate on how the pages interact. Let's call it PAGE 1 (/views/Frontend)

```
@extends('Layout.mainlayout')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<body>
<!-- Listing -->
                        @foreach ($blog as $post)   
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                            <div class="blog__item">
                                <div class="blog__item__pic">
                                    <img src="img/blog/blog-2.jpg" alt="">
                                </div>
                                <div class="blog__item__text">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> May 4,2019</li>
                                        <li><i class="fa fa-comment-o"></i> 5</li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <h5><a href="/blog/{{ $post["slug"] }}">{{ $post["title"] }}</a></h5>
                                    <p>{{ $post["writings"] }} </p>
                                    <a href="/blog/{{ $post["slug"] }}" class="blog__btn">Selengkapnya <span class="arrow_right"></span></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @endforeach
```

As you can see, I tried to simulate where I picked data from a 'database', called the 'slugs' and 'writings' variable. To demonstrate this, I build PAGE 1 ROUTE

```
Route::get('/blog', function () {
    $blog_posts = [
        [
            "title" => "Judul Post 1",
            "slug" => "judul-post-1",
            "author" => "Author 1",
            "images" => "Gambar 1",
            "writings" => "Tulisan 1",
        ],
    ];

    return view('FrontEnd.blog', [
        "title" => "Blog",
        "blog" => $blog_posts
    ]);
});
```

From that one, I tried to redirect it to another page, let's call it PAGE 2 (/views/Frontend)

```
@extends('Layout.mainlayout')
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zxx">

<body>
<!-- Content -->
<!-- Content End -->
</body>
```

To connect those pages, I create PAGE 2 ROUTE, where I use the slugs to name the web page

```
Route::get('/blog/{slug}', function ($slug) {
    return view('FrontEnd.blogdetails', [
        "title" => "Blog Details"
    ]);
});
```

==================================================================================

My question is, **Why is the layout is not applied on PAGE 2?** When I tried to access the PAGE 2 independently (basically changes it as the 'home' page), the layout applies/work. Where did I go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get it, why you are using `<!DOCTYPE html>` on every inner page. Let me explain how its done correctly.

1. You need to define a layout under `views/layouts` let's call it.

```
<!-- resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php -->
<html>
    <head>
        <title>App Name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
 
        <div class="container">
            <!-- this is where content will be shown -->
            @yield('content') 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

2. Now, on the controller we are returning the view.

```
return view ('frontend.blog.index',compact('data'));
```

3. Nex, on this blade file we need to extend the layout.

```
<!-- resources/views/frontend/blog/index.blade.php -->
@extends('layouts.app')
 
@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```

In this way, you could solve the layout mystery.

For detail, visit https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#defining-a-layout.

Some of the issues I notice on your code:

- you are missing the yield field example `@yield('content')`
- next on your view file you need to call `@section('content') ... @endsection`

#PS:(you can replace `content` text with body or anything you like.)

Comment: I already follow your steps by using `@yield` , such as
```<!-- layout/main.blade.php -->
<body>
            @yield('content')
</body>
```
And for the page, I use such as
```
<!-- resources/views/frontend/page.blade.php -->
@extends('layout.main')
@section('content')
    <p>This is my body content.</p>
@endsection
```
But still, the layout for the page won't applied for the PAGE 2. In other pages, it works better (thank you). I think my problems is about the routing and the use of my `slug`, which now I think I need a cool head to grasp the concept haha

Comment: You might need to use assets this way. ```    <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
``` else it might how relative path according to your route file